# Scraping website to get game data: NoneType error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am running the below code to scrape [www.oddsportal.com](http://www.oddsportal.com)

While the code works perfectly well, however, some URLs dont have any data on the page and hence, I get a NoneType error as the page is missing elements.

How can I add "If no data on the page, go to next URL" to this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data


urls = {
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/ghana/premier-league-2014-2015/results/#/page/3/"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        game_data = parse_data(url)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

print(tabulate(results, headers='keys', tablefmt="github"))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_26.py", line 76, in <module>
    game_data = parse_data(url)
  File "C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_26.py", line 44, in parse_data
    count = main.findAll('a')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Also, sometimes the webpage fails to load. How can I trigger selenium to retry url if it does not load?

Thanks

Comment: What is your understanding of the error message? Can you tell me something that must be true about `main` in order for this error to occur? Can you think of a way to test for that? Do you see how to use that test to decide whether to retry the URL? Can you write the code so that the URL is retried in that case? Exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: The error message means that there is no object and could not find content. `main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})` I dont know how to test for that.

Comment: The error message is telling you `main` is `NoneType`.  So the simplest fix is `if main is None: return None`.   This fix does not handle urls that don't load, though.

Comment: What's interesting is not how you got the value of `main`, but what that value *is*. There is no such thing as a Python variable referring to "no object". It instead refers to the special object `None`. You can test for that explicitly.

Comment: @RufusVS Where can I update `if main is None: return None` in the code?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am very new to the development journey. My debugger does not show (or I am not looking at the right place) what the value is in `main`

Comment: You don't need a debugger for this. When the error occurs, you know that the value is `None`, *because of what the error says*. `None` is *the only possible* `'NoneType' object`, *by design*. Which is why you get advised to use `is` to test for it, honouring that uniqueness.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ah right. I get that now. How can I modify the code to loop to next url if the object is `NoneType` ?

Comment: @PyNoob Immediately before the error line, of course.  Right after `main` gets assigned the return value of `content.find` (which is clearly None on some occasions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment clearer, here's an edit of parse_data:

```
def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    # return if not found.
    if main is None:
        return None       
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data
```